# Javascript: How can i show my app version running specific command for example "-version" on browser console

Tags: javascript, console

How can i show my app version using Javascript on console of the browser vy typing specific command for example "-version" and automatically recognizing the version of the app placed on the javascript file.

[image]

I dont want to show it like this only when i type the command -version can be shown

```
console.info('App Version: 0.0.1');
```

Comment: `-version` won't work since JavaScript will interpret `-` as the unary minus operator. Your application can create a global variable `version` that contains the version number or a function that returns the version number.